# Why is preg_match() not returning for number format?

Tags: php

I know this is a simple question. I can't seem to find the answer. I am trying to get the number only.. but it returns 1.. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help

```
$test = preg_match("/[0-9]/","(469) 552-6500");
```

Comment: You need delimiters around the regular expression. Check the documentation

Comment: @miken32 I tried adding it

Comment: @miken32 I tried adding it and it just returns as 1

Comment: `preg_match` only returns 1 match. The third parameter should be used for returning the matches. `preg_match_all` should be used for all the matches.

Comment: What, *exactly* are you trying to return? Are you trying to return the phone number without spaces or parentheses? `4695526500` Or are you trying to find if you have a match of any of the numbers? What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: I voted this question as unclear, given you didn't say what the results you wanted to get. @JayBlanchard asked for this already and you never responded.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to return only the numbers -- You should be using `preg_replace` in my opinion.  Also you need the `/` and delimiters.

```
echo preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', '(469) 552-6500');
```

This will return:

```
4695526500
```

Comment: The OP is trying to make sure they have matches, not replace anything. But I can see where you would think that.

Comment: Ah .. "I am trying to get the number only" --  That's the part I read into as the "problem"

Comment: Me too - and that is why I said that. If that is the case then your answer would be 100% correct. I'll ask him for clarification.

Comment: Glad I could assist.  You can accept my answer if this solved your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Echoing `$test` will return 1 (true) if there is a match and 0 (false) if there isn't a match but you must use delimiters ( `/` ) around your "needle". Better to store the matched array and test against the returned array:

```
$test = preg_match("/[0-9]/","(469) 552-6500", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
)
```